# Inserted models appear bigger than expected and on the back of camera

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, usdz

Here is the properties of model that appears fine.

[image]

And here is the properties of model that has problems and appears bigger and above the camera view:

[image]

Here is my code to insert the model:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
    // My Custom Class
    guard let model = modelConfirmedForPlacement else { return } 

    if let modelEntity = model.modelEntity {
        print("Adding model to scene: \(model.modelName)")
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .any)
        let readyModelEntity = modelEntity.clone(recursive: true)
        //Add Gestures Support for Model
        readyModelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        anchorEntity.addChild(readyModelEntity)
        uiView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        // Install Gestures
        uiView.installGestures([.all], for: readyModelEntity)
    } else {
        print("Unable to load modelEntity for: \(model.modelName)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        modelConfirmedForPlacement = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working units of RealityKit and SceneKit are **`meters`**, but default working units of some 3D apps are **`centimeters`**. Your metrics show the size of a huge RealityKit model's bounding box:

```
SIMD<Float>(x: 54.915, y: 45.507, z: 28.351)
```

To assign a new scale for an anchor entity or for a model entity (100...200 times smaller) use this:

```
let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity()
anchorEntity.scale = [1, 1, 1] * 0.01
```

To control model's position you must take into consideration a location of model's pivot point. Usually you can do it in 3D authoring app (like Maya or Blender) – a position of pivot point should be at a bottom of a model. In case you can't change pivot's position in 3D authoring app, just move a model's corresponding anchor:

```
anchorEntity.position.y = -0.5
```

...or if you want to move a model entity use children's deep hierarchy to get to it:

```
print(modelEntity)

modelEntity.children[0]..........children[0].position.y = -0.5
```